# How do i send a response to react?

Tags: reactjs, express

I have a login component and I sended a post request to the server containing the username  and password then after I recieved the data in the backend I will match it to the SELECT query result from the backend and after I want send a data to the client from the server...

Here's my login code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios'


function Login() {

const [account, setAccount] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
})


function handleClick(event) {

    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
        username: account.username,
        password: account.password
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Account Logged In");
    })
    event.preventDefault();
}

function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setAccount(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }))
}

return (

    <div className="float shadow bg-light px-3 py-3 ai-center js-between my-3">
        <h2 className="brand color-olive">Furns</h2>
        <h1 className="color-olive">Login</h1>
        <form className="column">
            <label htmlFor="username" className="color-olive my-1"> Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" className="txt-box" name="username" value={account.username} onChange={handleChange} />

            <label htmlFor="password" className="color-olive my-1">Password </label>
            <input id="password" type="password" className="txt-box" name="password" value={account.password} onChange={handleChange} />


            <button type="submit" className="mt-4 olive login-btn-large w-100" onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>

            <Link to="/">
                <button className="my-1 olive bg-light btn-cancel w-100">Cancel</button>
            </Link>

        </form>

    </div>

);
}

export default Login;
```

And here's the code in the server:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
var selectAccount = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=? AND password=?";
db.query(selectAccount, [username, password], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

//I want to match the query results with the user input the send a boolean to the login component
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about SQL Syntax, but here is the way you can do this.

- Find first with `username`
- If no record is found, then `User does not exist` response.
- Else, check if `results[0].password !== password`, then send `wrong password`
- Else, the password is right and send `success response`

You can send `response` using `res.send({/*data inside*/})`. Here, I used a `custom status code`, so that error handling at frontend become easy.

---

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
   const username = req.body.username;
   const password = req.body.password;
   var selectAccount = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=?";
   db.query(selectAccount, [username], function (err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
       if(results.length === 0) return res.send({status: 404, msg: "No user found"});
       if(results[0].password !== password) return res.send({status: 400, msg:"Wrong Password"})
       return res.send({status: 200, msg:"Login Successful"})
   })
})
```

Comment: after that how would I read the data in react?

Comment: can I just send a object to from the express to react then read it on react???

Comment: You can refer this blog. You are already using `Axios` so the blog is associated with this only. https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/17/react-axios-http-post-request-examples


Yes, you can send the object from express to react. You can read the handling the data using axios on react side. 

If this clears your doubts, then u can upvote and click green tick to close the question